# Why are there three ways to get the manual in Git?

Tags: git

I've been brushing up on Git by reading, *Pro Git 2nd Ed.*, and the book gives the reader three ways to get the manual for a Git verb.

```
$ git help <verb> 
$ git <verb> --help 
$ man git-<verb>
```

Why did the developers of Git feel this complication was necessary?

**Update:** 
I used the link as suggested in the comments by @JoeClay and sent an email. I will update this Q&A when a response come through.

Comment: _"Why did the developers of Git feel this complication was necessary?"_ - I think most people who use Git ask themselves that question several times a day :p

Comment: @JoeClay Is that why there are so many down votes? lol

Comment: In all seriousness, it's probably because the only people who are going to truly know the answer to this question are the Git devs themselves. You're probably better off asking on [their mailing list, or something along those lines](https://git-scm.com/community).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @JoeClay, I asked the question through the mailing list and here is the response from a responder named Philip Oakley:

"It is (IIUC) in a general sort of way "by design", and a little bit of
 accident."

> Historically git was a set of shell scripts named git-*, so each stood
>   alone.
>
> Then there was the great consolidation (around V1.6?) which created
>   the modern `git ' approach, with every command normally having 
>   -h and --help options for short form usage and long form man pages.
>
> The option capability became standardised. Also a `git help <cmd>`
>   command was created. Underneath there are still the (backward
>   compatible) git-* forms. The help command allowed selection of display
>   type, so that on Unix/Linux man was the norm, while an --html (or
>   --web) option is available for those who like the pretty browser view
>
> The help commnad just converts the parameters to achieve the expected
>   display (with various fallbacks if the command or guide is missing,
>   etc)
>
> Meanwhile on Windows, the man facility was not ported as part of git,
>   so it defaults to the --web version. If you are on Windows, and
>   download the SDK as well you can install the man viewer and other
>   goodies

So it appears that the reason for multiple commands are a side effect of preference changes with later versions of Git, and operability with different operating systems.